# Gitlab/Gitolite issue while cloning repo

Tags: git, ssh, gitolite, gitlab

I have setup a Gitlab strictly according to [manual from the gitlab wiki](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/stable/doc/installation.md). It works. I have a web access, I can create a project too (and git repo has been created after it). All is ok.

But when I try clone the newly created project repo with

```
git clone git@git.myserver.com:myproject.git
```

from the my development machine the server says that I need to enter password for the **git** user (this user have no password). I think it should auth me with key I provided.

My environment: I've successfully created the ssh keys on my dev machine, set the **HOME** environment variable to C:\Users\. Ssh is correctly authorize user with keys to other servers (and to this server too).
Also I've added the generated keys for my **git** user.

Next command is also working fine from the local server user (this is according to manual too):

```
sudo -u gitlab -H git clone git@localhost:gitolite-admin.git /tmp/gitolite-admin
```

My **authorized_keys** file for the git user is like:

```
# gitolite start
command="/home/git/bin/gl-auth-command gitlab",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa <LONG_KEY_HERE> gitlab@odiszapc
# gitolite end
```

Should there be my user key in the **authorized_keys** file after I've added ssh key from gitlab web console? Guys, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I've got it.

When I add key for the user from web interface, it hasn't been added to **authorized_keys** file. What I do is make full delete of the gitolite installation and then reinstall it according to native manual from the [gitolite wiki](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/). Now when i've add a key to user, this key is added to **authorized_keys** and all works fine now.

Comment: I have edited my answer to emphasizes the step which would detect this issue sooner.

Answer (score 3):

That means that:

- ether your public/private ssh keys aren't found locally (in your `~/.ssh` directory)
- or the public key hasn't been registered in the server `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` by gitlab (which seems to be the case here: addig your ssh key should trigger its publication by gitlab).
  This is similar to **[GitLab issue 900](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/900)**.
  You could have copy-paste your key with linebreaks in it.

> **Remove linebreaks from key before persisting**.

You will know more with a:

```
ssh -vvv git@git.myserver.com
```

Note that all operations on the server are done as user 'git', which is why it falls back asking the `git` password. [This is how gitolite works with ssh](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/glssh.html).

---

As the OP mentions, the issue was about gitolite not being properly installed.
This is the kind of issue which should be detected by the "verification step" of GitLab:

```
sudo -u gitlab bundle exec rake gitlab:app:status RAILS_ENV=production
```

It should produce, regarding gitolite (I have added the '`vvv`' and '`^^^`' for emphasis):

```
# OUTPUT EXAMPLE
Starting diagnostic
config/database.yml............exists
config/gitlab.yml............exists
/home/git/repositories/............exists
/home/git/repositories/ is writable?............YES

vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

remote: Counting objects: 603, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (466/466), done.
remote: Total 603 (delta 174), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (603/603), 53.29 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (174/174), done.
Can clone gitolite-admin?............YES

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

UMASK for .gitolite.rc is 0007? ............YES
```

If it does not, then a re-installation of Gitolite is in order.