# Tunnel ssh through another user

Tags: linux, ssh, gitolite, su, ssh-tunnel

Note: In the second part of the email I will explain how I came across to this problem, namely through gitolite. But the issue is an `ssh` issue rather than a `gitolite` issue. Still, I added the gitolite tag in case someone has an ad hoc solution for the specific case.

Here's the general problem.

I have a server with two users, `alice` and `bob`. `alice` can assume `bob` identity via `su - bob`, but she does not know `bob`'s password (for whatever reason). From her laptop Alice would like to ssh into the server as `bob`, but she can't since she hasn't his password. Is there a way to exploit her ability to assume `bob`'s identity to mimic the behavior of `ssh bob@server`? In a way, I would like to *tunnel*  the ssh connection through a change of user identity. I think this is a long shot, I'm guessing ssh does not allow this. But I figured I'd ask anyways.

**Where does the problem come from: gitolite**

I am trying to use gitolite. I got the server administrator to set up the `gitolite` user and he gave me the power to do `su - gitolite` on the server. However, he did not give me `gitolite`'s password, and given the time of the day, the server admin has gone home, so I have to wait till tomorrow to ask him that password. Meanwhile, I would like to find a workaround (if possible), just for fun.

Brief gitolite-ssh interaction recap (as far as I understand): the `authorized_keys` file in `gitolite/.ssh` has lines like this

```
# gitolite start
command="/usr/share/gitolite3/gitolite-shell some_user_name",no-portforwarding,
no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa SOME_USER_NAME_KEY
# gitolite end
```

So the whole gitolite machinery is activated when an authorized key tries to ssh into `gitolite`'s account. In fact, when an authorized key sshs (how do you conjugate the verb 'to ssh'?!?) into `gitolite`'s account, `gitolite-shell` is executed and takes over, allowing only `git` related commands. You may ask "then why do you need `gitolite`'s password if you are one of its authorized keys? Glad you asked. In order for `some_user_name` to modify the configuration of gitolite, it is not enough to add a line like those to `~gitolite/.ssh/authorized_keys`; `some_user_name` needs to be added to gitolite's configuration file, which is stored inside the git repository in `~gitolite/repository/gitolite-admin.git`. In order to change this config file, one has to clone that repo, modify the config file, and push the repo back. The catch: the users allowed to push modifications in the `gitolite-admin` repo are listed in the `gitolite-admin` repo itself... At the beginning, the user that initialized gitolite (in this case, the user `gitolite`) is the only one listed in such config file. So I need to be able to access that conf file as `gitolite`, in order to add my user among the users that can change the configurations. Once I do that, I can forget about the user `gitolite` and administer the gitolite repositories as myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to exploit her ability to assume bob's identity to mimic the behavior of ssh bob@server?

Sure: if Alice can open a shell session as bob (with `su - bob`), she can:

- access to `/home/bob/.ssh`,
- copy his public and private key to `/home/alice/.ssh/id_rsa.bob.pub` and `id_rsa.bob`.
- open an ssh session as `bob` with `ssh -i /home/alice/.ssh/id_rsa.bob  bob@server` (or use an [`.ssh/config` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37374944/6309))

Don't forget to read:

- [how gitolite uses ssh](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/glssh.html),
- [illustrated in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11491498/6309),
- also presented here: "[How does Gitolite works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13320256/6309)"

Reminder: any use of gitolite is always done through the `git` or `gitolite` user, never as 'alice' or 'bob'.